# Problem in skype

Tags: skype, microphone, playback

I use Skype on my computer and when I try to call my friend so we can CoOp on MineCraft I have the problem of not being able to hear him and he is unable to hear me. I am using the Skype that is from Canonical Partners. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Check your sound configuration in system settings, then verify that pulseaudio is working properly in Skype from the settings menu.  Likely you just need to select the correct microphone.

Comment: I checked the sound config in the system settings and all out/input is selected as my headset. The volume is up.

Comment: The only microphone available is Virtual Device in Skype

Comment: Try installing the 32-bit pulseaudio libs.  The packages manager should have done that for you, but if not that's probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`usermod -G audio USERNAME` and replace USERNAME with your username.